# Push From UIKit to SwiftUI using navigation controllre is add Grey Rectanagle

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, navigationview

i used coordinator to navigate between pages

## UIKit Code

```
                    navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
                    navController.pushViewController(u, animated: true)
```

## SwiftUI Code

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    HeaderTopNotification()
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            ForEach(1..<10) { _ in
                                Section {
                                    Text("day")
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding(.vertical,12.h)
                                    VStack (alignment: .leading,spacing: 8.h){
                                        ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                                            NotificationCardView()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .background(content: {
                        Colors.backgroundUIView.toColor
                    })
                    .padding(.horizontal,Constant.marginScreen)
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Notifications")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
           .toolbarBackground(Colors.background.toColor, for: .navigationBar)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: example to grey rectangle dispaly in bootom screen]

when i remove Navigation view is hidden and work correctly

connnect UIKIT With SwiftUI And push swiftui screen to UINAvigationController

Comment: Can you rewrite the question again, not very clear? Also if you using UIKit for Navigation and SwiftUI for the UI, then stick to that. Remove NavigationView and style from SwiftUI and use the swiftUIView as the view.